# how can use Composite API to external API

Tags: rest-api, composite

Here is the scenario i am using `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode/users` and `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode/albums`, i want to call make composite call so that i can make both call in one go, which load albums only related to particular users and return final result by using referenceId. What I is see the example provided everywhere uses the workbench, i am thinking of using from apex class. is this possible? if possible can someone guide me to the right direction with some resource?

Thank you
JK

Comment: My first impression here is that I have no idea what you're trying to say, much less what you're trying to do. The keys to success here are: 1) Include plenty of detail about your issue. 2) Show us what you've tried. 3) Keep your question very narrow in scope.

Comment: Composite requests only work for select Salesforce (on-platform) resources.

Comment: @identigral exactly this is what  i wanted to know. I was trying to make multiple non Salesforce API endpoint in one request. Thank you